# Function to undo point excursion

Tags: point, save-excursion

I know that I can use `save-excursion` to avoid changes to `(point)`, is there a similar function to revert excursion based on the value of BODY. For example:

```
(revert-excursion BODY)
```

would revert the excursion if `BODY` evaluates to `nil` otherwise the new value of `(point)` is maintained. I could of course do this by saving the previous `(point)` and using `(goto-char)` conditionally, or by executing `BODY` twice (one to evaluate its value and the second to actually move `(point)`. But I am wondering if there are better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first idea is the best:

```el
   ...
   (goto-char (let ((pt (point)))
                (save-excursion 
                  (if BODY 
                     (point)
                    pt)))))
```

You could probably write a macro for it.

Evaluating BODY twice is not a good idea: it may have side-effects that make it non-idempotent, and/or it may be expensive to evaluate.